# Как сделать лог фаил на js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, как принимать значение из поля инпут и предать его в отдельный фаил.
Пример: есть инпут в который я буду вводить постоянно данные, эти данные должны записывать в отдельный лог фаил.

```html
<input type='text' name='mes'>
<button type='submit'>
```

Comment: Браузерный JavaScript выполняется в "песочнице", у которой нет доступа к файловой системе. Ваша задача реализуема разве что через написание расширения к браузеру, но для каждого браузера потребуется своё, а некоторые браузеры их вообще не поддерживают. Или речь идёт о node.js?

Comment: Если в лог файл на сервере - то достаточно создать там принимающий файл (например, php), который будет получать отправляемые через ajax post (или get) запросы с логами, и записывать их в какой-нибудь файл

Comment: Могли бы вы сделать пример, я пока с аяксом не знаком. $( "#siteinput" ).change(function() {
      $.post( "http://мой сайт/wp-content/themes/моятема/log.php", { message: $( this ).val() } );
    });  вот такая конструкция мне ничего не вернула, файл пустой.

Comment: А что делает log.php? Он должен из POST-сообщения вытащить message и записать непосредственно в лог-файл.

Comment: можно примет того как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS выполняется на стороне клиента и не имеет доступ к файловой системе.
Как вариант - посылать запрос на сервер и уже там записывать логи, или, что более хорошо - использовать консоль браузера и `console.log();`.

---

Отправка запроса примерно такая.

```
$( "#id_кнопки" ).click(
    function() 
    { 
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'example.com/log.php',
                data: "log=" + $('#id_текстового_поля').val(),
            }
        );
    }
);
```

На стороне сервера распарсиваете глобальную переменную `$_POST`, `$_POST['log']` должна содержать значение текстового поля. (https://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php)

На самом примитивном уровне примерно так:

```
$f = fopen("файл_лога.log", "a");
fprintf($f, "%s\r\n", $_POST['log']);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: А как логи из консоли сохранить в файл?

Comment: @Darth: А зачем логи из консоли сохранять в файл?

Comment: Потому что человеку надо сохранить логи в файл,а вы ему console.log предлагаете